# Tag Input control in MVC razor?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to add ‘tag interface’ along with autocomplete feature. How does it work in mvc3 razor?

Here is the example http://maxwells.github.io/bootstrap-tags.html , http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/ 
[image]

Tag Interface control was not available in MVC .Please help me someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

> Chosen is a jQuery plugin that makes long, unwieldy select boxes much
>   more user-friendly.

Examples of its use with ASP.NET MVC:

[Chosen Multiselect Dropdown List with ASP.Net MVC3](http://utsavized.com/chosen-multiselect-dropdown-list-with-asp-net-mvc3/)

[Chosen and Jquery and MVC](http://msprogrammer.serviciipeweb.ro/2011/12/19/chosen-and-jquery-and-mvc/)